# flutter can't see its own widget

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Error Text:

```
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/scaffold.dart:1670:17: Error: Final field 'floatingActionButton' is not initialized.
Try to initialize the field in the declaration or in every constructor.
  final Widget? floatingActionButton;
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception
2

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1151

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU�LD FAILED in 1m 9s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I am getting this error in Flutter. Flutter doesn't see its own floatingactionbutton widget. It gives the same error when not using floatingactionbutton. I got this error in my own application. When I couldn't find the solution, I created a new flutter project. But the same error was in question in flutter's own counter implementation. How can i solve it. What I suspect is that I accidentally edited one of the flutter files opened after the error while writing fast code. sorry for my bad english

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the important part of your error:

```
C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/scaffold.dart:1670:17: Error: Final field 'floatingActionButton' is not initialized.
Try to initialize the field in the declaration or in every constructor.
  final Widget? floatingActionButton;
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You modified the `C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/scaffold.dart` file. You probably removed the `this.floatingActionButton,` from the `Scaffold` constructor.

What you can do is open your `cmd`, go to `C:/src/flutter`, and then do a `git checkout -- .`

This will undo all the changes you've made (by accident or on purpose) in your Flutter directory.

Comment: This is the first time I encounter such an error. I would be very grateful if you could give a more detailed answer. I understood the problem, but I could not fully grasp the solution. Should I do git checkout in windows cmd or vs code terminal? Thanks for help.

Comment: You can use either VS Code terminal or the `cmd`. Navigate to Flutter directory with `cd C:/src/flutter`. Then run exactly `git checkout -- .`. This will remove all changes that weren't staged or committed.

Comment: Your branch is behind 'origin/stable' by 10 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch) I get this message

Comment: Did you run the checkout command I gave you? It shouldn't output anything. The "you are 10 commits behind" is normal for `git status`.